# encode unicode characters to unicode escape sequences

Tags: python, json, django, unicode, iconv

I've a CSV file containing sites along with addresses. I need to work on this file to produce a json file that I will use in Django to load initial data to my database. To do that, I need to convert all special characters from the CSV file to unicode escaped characters.

Here is an example:

```
Örnsköldsvik;SE;Ornskoldsvik;Ångermanlandsgatan 28 A
```

It should be converted to:

```
\u00D6rnsk\u00F6ldsvik;SE;Ornskoldsvik;\u00C5ngermanlandsgatan 28 A
```

The following site is doing exactly the conversion I'm expecting: http://itpro.cz/juniconv/ but I'de like to find a way to do it from command line (bash) or in python. I've already tried using `iconv`, `uconv` and some python scripts without real success.

What kind of script is running behind the `juniconv` website?

Thank you in avance for any suggestion.

Comment: *"To do that, I need to convert all special characters from the CSV file to unicode escaped characters."* Why? If you ensure that you're being consistent about character sets (UTF-8 is a good choice for nearly all western texts), there's no need.

Comment: Actually, when I'm dumping my data with `./manage.py dumpdata app.model > dump.json`, this is the way data are encoded in `dump.json`. This is why I'd like to have the same format to load data.

Comment: If you want JSON output, why not use `json.dump()`? There is more to producing JSON string literal output than just `\u` escapes.

Comment: There's a pure bash method described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51309827/1003113

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to get [Unicode escapes similar to Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.3) in Python; you could [use JSON format](http://www.json.org/):

```
>>> import json
>>> import sys
>>> s = u'Örnsköldsvik;SE;Ornskoldsvik;Ångermanlandsgatan 28 A'
>>> json.dump(s, sys.stdout)
"\u00d6rnsk\u00f6ldsvik;SE;Ornskoldsvik;\u00c5ngermanlandsgatan 28 A"
```

There is also, `unicode-escape` codec but you shouldn't use it: it produces Python-specific escaping (how Python Unicode string literals look like):

```
>>> print s.encode('unicode-escape')
\xd6rnsk\xf6ldsvik;SE;Ornskoldsvik;\xc5ngermanlandsgatan 28 A
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! Thans a lot.

Comment: Can't this be done with pure bash?

Comment: @MartynasJusevičius sure. Though the question has `python` tag, so it is used to produce json in the answer. `python` can be called from bash too. There are many other tools that can produce json.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with GNU libiconv's --unicode-subst option:

```
$ echo 'Örnsköldsvik;SE;Ornskoldsvik;Ångermanlandsgatan 28 A' | \
  iconv -t ASCII --unicode-subst='\u%04X'
\u00D6rnsk\u00F6ldsvik;SE;Ornskoldsvik;\u00C5ngermanlandsgatan 28 A
```

Incidentally, GNU libiconv also has a pseudo-encoding called JAVA that does this:

```
$ echo 'Örnsköldsvik;SE;Ornskoldsvik;Ångermanlandsgatan 28 A' | \
  iconv -t JAVA
\u00d6rnsk\u00f6ldsvik;SE;Ornskoldsvik;\u00c5ngermanlandsgatan 28 A
```

Note: GNU libiconv is *not* the iconv included in with glibc. It's a separate package that is usually not installed on glibc systems because glibc's iconv is just as good for 99% of the purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this might help you? I assume you have a utf-8 string...

```
import csv
csv_reader = csv.reader(utf8_data)
for row in csv_reader:
    encoded_row = [unicode(cell, 'utf-8') for cell in row]
    #print(encoded_row)
```

Comment: Thank you for trying to help but this is not exactly what I'm looking for. Indeed, it outputs: `\xd6rnsk\xf6ldsvik;208;Ornskoldsvik;\xc5ngermanlandsgatan 28 A` instead of unicode escape notation (`\u....`)

Comment: While I'm finding a more appropriate solution, I've replaced all special characters as follows: `iconv -f utf-8 -t ASCII//TRANSLIT < input.csv > output.csv`

Answer (score 0):

You can always use Visual Studio Code and install the ascii-unicode-escape extension. Once installed, you can use Ctrl-Shift-P and run the 'Escape non-ASCII characters' command.