# How do you convert unicode string to escapes in bash?

Tags: bash, shell, unicode, character-encoding

I need a tool that will translate the unicode string into escape characters like \u0230.

For example,

```
echo ãçé | convert-unicode-tool
\u00e3\u00e7\u00e9
```

Comment: StackOverflow is NOT a "please write me a script" service. What did you try so far ?

Comment: The conversion depends on the input encoding (listed by the command `locale`). The answers given here neglect this issue. There is a [encoding-independent solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61791503/6770384) for [this duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61791233/6770384) (couldn't answer here since the question is closed).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All bash method -

```
echo ãçé |
   while read -n 1 u
   do [[ -n "$u" ]] && printf '\\u%04x' "'$u"
   done
```

That leading apostrophe is a printf formatting/interpretation guide.

From [the GNU man page online](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/printf-invocation.html#printf-invocation):

> If the leading character of a numeric argument is ‘"’ or ‘'’ then its value is the numeric value of the immediately following character. Any remaining characters are silently ignored if the POSIXLY_CORRECT environment variable is set; otherwise, a warning is printed. For example, ‘printf "%d" "'a"’ outputs ‘97’ on hosts that use the ASCII character set, since ‘a’ has the numeric value 97 in ASCII.

That lets us pass the character to printf for numeric interpretations such as %d or %03o, or here, %04x.

The `[[ -n "$u" ]]` is because there's a null trailing byte that will otherwise be appended as `\u0000`.

Output:

```
$:     echo ãçé |
>        while read -n 1 u
>        do [[ -n "$u" ]] && printf '\\u%04x' "'$u"
>        done
\u00e3\u00e7\u00e9
```

Without the null byte check -

```
$: echo ãçé | while read -n 1 u; do printf '\\u%04x' "'$u";done
\u00e3\u00e7\u00e9\u0000
```

Comment: NOTE: `-n` respects (and so ignores) valid delimiters like space, tab, and newline. If you want it to pick those up too, use `-N`.

Comment: Thanks. In order to avoid problems with spaces, I use this approach:
    for (( i = 0; i < ${#string}; i++ )); do
    c="${string:1}";
    printf '\\u%04x' "'$c";
    done;

Comment: Instead of the read -n?

Answer (score 0):

```
› echo -n ãçé | perl -C -e'print for map { sprintf "\\u%04x", ord } split //, readline'
\u00e3\u00e7\u00e9
```

Comment: Why the `for`? Works fine without. `$: echo -n ãçé | perl -C -e'print map { sprintf "\\u%04x", ord } split //, readline'`
\u00e3\u00e7\u00e9

Comment: Because I confused it with `print "listexpr in babycart"` (effectively the same as `print "@arrayvar"`) which intersperses output with spaces; `for` iteration protects against that.

Comment: And didn't hurt anything here. :)