# How to convert Unicode string to Unicode escape sequences?

Tags: bash

I want input a string and output its unicode string, like this "\uXXXX\uXXXX".

Now I already tried two way, but they all output utf-8. How should I do?

```sh
printf "文" | hexdump -e '"%X"'
# 8796E6
printf "文" | xxd -pu
# e69687
```

Comment: iconv command is used to convert some text in one encoding into another encoding. `iconv options -f from-encoding -t to-encoding inputfile(s) -o outputfile`  Please check url https://www.tecmint.com/convert-files-to-utf-8-encoding-in-linux/

Comment: Good! It solve my question, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Literals of the form `\uXXXX` correspond to UTF-16 encoding. So you have to convert your string into that encoding first before hexdumping it.

After the conversion to UTF-16 you can hexdump in groups of 4 bytes and post-process the dump with `sed` to insert the leading `\u`. Here we use `od` instead of `xdd` because `od` is usually pre-installed. Watch out for issues with the byte order / endianness.

```
printf '文' | iconv -t UTF16LE | od -t x2 -An -v | sed 's/ /\\u/g'
```

or longer but less hacky and platform-independent (`od` defaults to the system's endianness)

```
printf '文' | iconv -t UTF16BE | od -t x2 -An -v --endian=big | sed 's/ /\\u/g'
```

Comment: Thanks! I using `printf '文字' | iconv -t UTF16BE | od -t x2 -An -v | sed 's/ /\\u/g'` to get the unicode string.

Comment: @LianSheng Glad I could help. Please note that I made a mistake. The output encoding should be UTF16LE instead of UTF16BE because `od` swaps the endianess. I edited my answer so that the bytes in `\u1234` are no longer swapped as `\u3412`.