# Convert UTF-8 properties text file to Java ResourceBundle, converting Umlauts and Special Signs to HEX

Tags: java, character-encoding, resourcebundle

My customer provided me with special new translations for existing Java Resource Bundles in Excel format.

Now I try to convert this Excel sheet as automatically as possible to a new ResourceBundle file, representing the new language translations.

Some of the languages bring Umlauts / special signs, like Swedish, Hungarian, etc.

It is easy to export the Excel sheet to a properties text file with

```
<resource key> = <translation>
```

But how can I automatically convert the special characters to HEX representation usually used in Resource Bundle files?
Like  ü = \u00fc and so on.

Best would be a Java-centric solution.

Comment: Have you tried with [`native2ascii`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/native2ascii.html)? It is a tool included in the jdk distribution, suitable for resource bundle special characters conversions.

Comment: This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36942612/2834978) seems to do what you want.

Comment: @jccampanero, thanks! Exactly what I was looking for. No programming/scripting needed, just an in/out tool, which exactly does, what I was looking for.
This should be the answer - not the referenced question, which involves scripting.

Comment: That is great @Windwalker. I am happy to hear that the information was helpful. And I agree with you, I vote for reopen the question: the provided solution even does not use java, it is python based. Any way, the important thing is that your problem is solved.

Comment: @Basil-Bourque Please, can you consider reopening the question? As the OP indicates, and in my opinion as well, in the specific use case of Java I think native2ascii is the best solution possible, it is the purpose of the tool, and not a Python based one like the solution proposed in the linked answer, even not standard, but based on the use of the `json` library. Thank you very much.

Comment: @jccampanero Re-opened.

Comment: Thanks, @BasilBourque for re-opening.
I added a little sentence to the question, stating that I am looking for no programming solution, but a ready-to-use tool.

Comment: @Windwalker That makes this Question off-topic for Stack Overflow. 
"Seeking recommendations for books, tools, software libraries, and more
This question is likely to lead to opinion-based answers." is a specific reason to close a question. See sister site, [*Software Recommendations Stack Exchange*](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Thanks, @BasilBourque.
I re-formulated my last sentence.